# Windows 98 hacked just by visiting a website?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I am wondering how this was possible. I remember my cousin used to use the family computer and it was infected with viruses just by browsing the internet. I recall a bunch of our desktop icons turned into ads for online casinos, and every time we opened internet explorer we were bombarded with ad popups.

This was back in the late 90s/early 2000s.

Comment: It's called drive-by-download attacks and they were omnipresent in the past due to security problems with the browsers, especially around ActiveX, Flash, Java and Javascript. For more read [Can you get virus just by visiting a website in Chrome?](/questions/3848/), [How can a malicious URL affect a computer?](/questions/41122/), [Realistically, how likely it is to have a computer compromised from browsing random websites?](/questions/255698/), [Is it possible to gain control of a Windows computer with no browser notifications when a user clicks a URL?](/questions/111172/), ...

Comment: This is a trick question ... windows 98 is an OS, it cant be used to view websites.  But yah, lots of the browsers use at that time where super super vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have *remote code execution* (RCE) vulnerabilities that allow attackers to run code on the system when the user just visits a website (drive-by-download attacks). This is not just in history, but such vulnerabilities have been found even in 2023.

The browsers these days have *sandboxed* renderer processes; a vulnerability in the renderer must be chained with a *sandbox escape* vulnerability to be this effective. In the era of Windows 98 this kind of countermeasures didn't exist, so compromises were common.

Comment: Another important factor was that there was no auto update mechanisms, and downloading large software packages was problematic. In 2000 people had 56k modem, and a Netscape installer was [45 minutes to download](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/netscape-4-7-2). Old vulnerabilities was thus known, but rarely patched by end users.